# Ctrl+C won't close man pages

Tags: 10.04, putty, manpage

I'm setting up a Linode server, and connecting to it via SSH with PuTTY.

When I bring up a man page, and don't want to go through the whole thing, I'm used to doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the Unix boxes I've worked with.  This doesn't do anything for me in this situation, and I end up having to close the window, and reconnect.

Is there a way to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to work normally, or is there a different key sequence in Ubuntu that will implement the break?

Comment: Why don't you use **q** key to close man "environment"?

Comment: +1 good question!  I had this exactely same problem had to force reboot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can quit `man` (which uses `less`) by pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

This incessant trapping of the interrupt signal (control C) has been bothering me for many years.  When I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in a program, it's because I want keyboard control back, and I want that control back immediately, with prejudice.  There's no reason for something like 'less' to ignore control C.  It's a bad design decision.

Fortunately, there's another key combination which is not (yet) being ignored by most programs:  control-\.  This sends an 'abort' signal which is generally not trapped that also serves to give you back control of your terminal.